# how to write a gulpfile using a language that requires transpilation (babel)?

Tags: gulp

I am learning gulp and practicing writing gulpfile.js. gulp is for transforming js etc files. however, if I want to write gulpfile.js using es6, I may need to involve babel. I notice the following doc:  https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/javascript-and-gulpfiles#transpilation

[image]

but I still am still confused. why I rename this file and how does it compile 'import' syntax?  "gulpfile transpilation documentation" is broken. please help

Thanks